# Macro to loop through a web query - keeps bombing

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have built a macro intended to loop through stock tickers and in a column and use a web query to pull data on those stock tickers from yahoo finance

It runs fine for 10,15,20 web queries but without fail bombs out excel at some point in the first 20 or 30 web queries

I will be the first to say that I am an extreme amateur at VBA code, but I've tried a few things to address this issue (clearing cache, using pauses) and they haven't seemed to work.

It doesn't fail on the same item every time, but it always has the "connecting to web" text in the status bar, so I feel like it has something to do with the connection timing out, but I'm not sure how to attack it at this point.  Any ideas would be welcomed, as well as any code optimization I may be missing.. thanks!

```
Sub GetData()

    Application.Calculation = xlManual

     ' make the website a variable
    Dim sURL As String
    Dim Ticker As String
    Dim iRow As Integer
    Dim iCol As Integer
    Dim wqError As ErrObject

     ' create web query if it doesn't exist

    If Worksheets("query").QueryTables.Count = 0 Then
        With Worksheets("query").QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;", Destination:=Range("Query!A1"))
            .Name = "market_data.asp"
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .BackgroundQuery = False
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
            .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
            .WebTables = "4"
            .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
            .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
            .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
            .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
            .WebDisableRedirections = False
        End With
    End If

    iRow = 2
    iCol = 2

     'Loop through Tickers

    Do While Worksheets("Data").Range("A" & iRow).Value <> ""

            Ticker = Worksheets("Data").Range("A" & iRow).Value
            sURL = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=" & Ticker

            With Worksheets("query")
                .Cells.Clear
                .QueryTables(1).Connection = "URL;" & sURL
                On Error Resume Next
                .QueryTables(1).Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
                Set wqError = Err
                On Error GoTo 0

                If wqError.Number = 0 Then 'No error

                    .Range("B1").Copy Worksheets("Data").Cells(iRow, iCol)
                    .Range("B5").Copy Worksheets("Data").Cells(iRow, iCol + 1)
                    .Range("B13:B14").Copy Worksheets("Data").Cells(iRow, iCol + 2)
                    .Range("B18").Copy Worksheets("Data").Cells(iRow, iCol + 4)
                    .Range("B15").Copy Worksheets("Data").Cells(iRow, iCol + 5)
                    .Range("B22").Copy Worksheets("Data").Cells(iRow, iCol + 6)
                    .Range("B16").Copy Worksheets("Data").Cells(iRow, iCol + 7)
                    .Range("B20").Copy Worksheets("Data").Cells(iRow, iCol + 8)
                    .Range("B19").Copy Worksheets("Data").Cells(iRow, iCol + 9)
                    .Range("B25").Copy Worksheets("Data").Cells(iRow, iCol + 10)
                    .Range("B24").Copy Worksheets("Data").Cells(iRow, iCol + 11)

                ElseIf wqError.Number <> 1004 Then

                     'Report error because it isn't the expected error 1004 Web query returned no data

                    MsgBox "Web query refresh for " & String(2, vbCrLf) & sURL & String(2, vbCrLf) & " returned error number " & wqError.Number & String(2, vbCrLf) & wqError.Description

                End If

            End With

        iRow = iRow + 1
        If iRow Mod 5 = 0 Then Delete_IE_Cache
        If iRow Mod 20 = 0 Then ActiveWorkbook.Save
        If iRow Mod 20 = 0 Then Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

    Loop

     'Format results

    With Sheets("data")
    Range("A:M").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    Range("A:A").NumberFormat = "Text"
    Range("D:D").NumberFormat = "Text"
    Range("I:I").NumberFormat = "Text"
    Range("B:C").NumberFormat = "0.00"
    Range("E:H").NumberFormat = "0.00"
    Range("K:M").NumberFormat = "0.00"
    End With

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: "bombs out excel" means "excel crashes"? "excel locks up"? Default timeouts can be upwards of 90 seconds. have you waited?

Comment: yeah sorry that wasn't great wording - I mean to say that I see the data being pasted row by row by the macro, then Excel goes into "not responding" mode and freezes up.

Comment: I've waited a couple minutes before to see if it would revive but it hasn't done so the few times I've tried

Comment: I am guessing it is the `Wait` call ("The Wait method suspends all Microsoft Excel activity and may prevent you from performing other operations on your computer while Wait is in effect"). An alternative construction could be a `DoEvents` call in a loop that compares Now with the desired elapsed time. ( such as here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21385844/ )

Comment: You might try to retrieve the necessary data via XHR and parsing like in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28788519/2165759).

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any code to wait for the page to finish loading... It might not be necessary, but it wouldn't hurt to put this at the top of your module and then call it after navigating to the website+stockticker.

```
Private Declare Sub AppSleep Lib "kernel32" Alias "Sleep" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
Public Sub PauseApp(PauseInSeconds As Long)
Call AppSleep(PauseInSeconds)
End Sub
```

Then in your code,

```
sURL = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=" & Ticker 
Call sleepie(sURL)
```

Like I said, it might not solve your problem at all but it most definitely will help.